# Incorporating refedit into Vlookup userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have a **vlookup userform** which autofills the details in the form based on the seat n°.

[image]

Now I want to incoroporate a ref edit to paste these data from the **text box** to the **cells** the user chooses with the refedit. Hence i would need some help in going about these. 
This is the code i have used.
 I potentially want to **insert** 3 refedit boxes for user to select the **cell** they want to paste each of the data (**Name**,**Dept** and **Ext No**.) from the **textbox**.

See my code below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Frame1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

   Dim answer As Integer
   answer = TextBox1.Value
   TextBox2.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(answer, Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Range("B:E"), 2, False)
   TextBox3.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(answer, Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Range("B:E"), 3, False)
   TextBox4.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(answer, Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Range("B:E"), 4, False)

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox4_Change()

End Sub
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()

    Unload Me
    End
End Sub
```

I have tried figuring out a code to solve this issue but I am getting an object required error. My rngcopy would be textbox2.value (Name) and the rngpaste location would be the ref edit 1.

This is the code

```
Private Sub PasteButton_Click()

Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range
Dim wsPaste As Range
Dim answer As Integer
answer = TextBox1.Value
If RefEdit1.Value <> "" Then

        TextBox2.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(answer, Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Range("B:E"), 2, False)
        Set rngCopy = TextBox2.Value
        Set wsPaste = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Replace(Split(TextBox2.Value, "!")(0), "'", ""))
        Set rngPaste = wsPaste.Range(Split(TextBox2.Value, "!")(1))

        rngCopy.Copy rngPaste
  Else
        MsgBox "Please select an Output range"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Step through your code with the LOCALS window open, and watch your range objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should get the row index with Match and expose it to the form so it can be used by the copy function.
And to set the target pointed by a Ref control, just evalute the .Value property with Range():

```
Range(RefEdit.Value).cells(1, 1) = Worksheet.Cells(row, column)
```

The form:

[image]

The code:

```
' constants to define the data
Const SHEET_DATA = "L12 - Data Sheet"
Const COLUMN_SEAT = "B"
Const COLUMNN_NAME = "C"
Const COLUMN_DEPT = "D"
Const COLUMN_EXTNO = "E"

Private Sheet As Worksheet
Private RowIndex As Long

Private Sub TxtSeatNo_Change()
  Dim seatno

  'clear the fields first
  Me.TxtName.value = Empty
  Me.TxtDept.value = Empty
  Me.TxtExtNo.value = Empty
  RowIndex = 0

  If Len(TxtSeatNo.value) Then
    Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SHEET_DATA)

    On Error Resume Next

    ' get the seat number to either string or double
    seatno = TxtSeatNo.value
    seatno = CDbl(seatno)

    ' get the row index containing the SeatNo
    RowIndex = WorksheetFunction.match(seatno, _
                                       Sheet.Columns(COLUMN_SEAT), _
                                       0)
    On Error GoTo 0
  End If

  If RowIndex Then
    ' copy the values from the sheet to the text boxes
    Me.TxtName.value = Sheet.Cells(RowIndex, COLUMNN_NAME)
    Me.TxtDept.value = Sheet.Cells(RowIndex, COLUMN_DEPT)
    Me.TxtExtNo.value = Sheet.Cells(RowIndex, COLUMN_EXTNO)
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub BtCopy_Click()
  If RowIndex < 1 Then Exit Sub

  ' copy the current values to the cells pointed by the ref controls

  If Len(Me.RefName.value) Then _
    Range(Me.RefName.value) = Sheet.Cells(RowIndex, COLUMNN_NAME)

  If Len(Me.RefDept.value) Then _
    Range(Me.RefDept.value) = Sheet.Cells(RowIndex, COLUMN_DEPT)

  If Len(Me.RefExtNo.value) Then _
    Range(Me.RefExtNo.value) = Sheet.Cells(RowIndex, COLUMN_EXTNO)
End Sub

Private Sub BtlClose_Click()
  ' close the form
  Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed coding:)

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your `rngCopy` as a **Range Object** and then later on you are binding it to a `.value` **method** of the range object.

`Set rngCopy = TextBox2.Value`

This is likely where you are encountering errors. Try declaring a `string` and assigning it to your copy value.

```
Dim string1 As String
string1 = TextBox2.Value
```

Step through your code editor with the **LOCALS** window open, and watch what happens to your `rngCopy` object when you assign a string to it.

Comment: Thank you for your help . I did try string but because my table of data has mixture of numbers and strings i had to adapt a different method. Thanks anyways!

Comment: happy to help. I guess the debugging suggestion was useful then :)