# VBA, Userform to alter keyword in code

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Never did any userform before, but is there a way to create a form/button/cells, as you fill them in, it replaces/changes a search term in my vba code?

```
  ' Find the Node column
            intColNode = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            intColNode = WorksheetFunction.Match("Node", .Rows(1), 0)
            On Error GoTo 0
```

Example would be to replace the word "Node" with what the user inputs. How can I create a form where a user of spreadsheet can alter keyword to desired taste.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Altering code that's being executed isn't usualy the greatest idea to keep your environment stable and in a not-exploding state. That said, you might want to research the VBE object model, aka VBIDE API.

Comment: Maybe explain better what you are trying to attempt, there should be no reason to change the code with additional code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a variable for the user input.  In this case a textbox should do the trick, then have a `Submit` button (Command Button in UserForm toolbox) that runs your code like the following:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim uVal as String
uVal = Userform1.Textbox1.Value

intColNode = 0
On Error Resume Next
intColNode = WorksheetFunction.Match(uVal, .Rows(1), 0)
On Error GoTo 0

Unload Me

End Sub
```

[Good page for learning how to create a UserForm](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html)

Answer (score 1):

I provided some code to another answer that seems to match your needs:

[Incorporating refedit into Vlookup userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36056496/incorporating-refedit-into-vlookup-userform?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Basically, when a user type a value in a field (SeatNo), the other fields are updated with the values from the same row.